# How can I use ImageAnnotatorClient with explicit authentication?

Tags: google-api, ocr

It is clear how to [use Storageclient with explicit authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application). It is also clear how to use [ImageAnnotatorClient with implicit authentication](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries). But how to use explicit authentication for ImageAnnotatorClient? It does not accept credenticals as input for the create method. I work with C#. I need the library for OCR purposes.

Answer (score 2):

If by "explicit" you mean loading your credentials file in code, here is how I did it in Scala (vision v1.20.0):

```
val visionClient = {
    val credStream = getInputStream( "my-api-key.json" )
    val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credStream)
    val imageAnnotatorSettings = ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder()
                     .setCredentialsProvider( FixedCredentialsProvider.create( credentials ) )
                     .build();
    ImageAnnotatorClient.create( imageAnnotatorSettings )
}
```

You should be able to do something similar in C#.